# Is it ok to write and read from file of objects concurrently?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Suppose i have an `ArrayList<Book>` and i store it in a file with method `writeObject()` of `ObjectOutputStream`. Is it ok for me to enable only one thread to write to file and many threads to read from that same file concurrently? Or should i have no reading at all if one thread is writing? I don't know what happens behind the scenes so i'am not sure how to handle this.

Comment: No, it's not OK unless you put in place some careful handling!

Comment: No. It is not safe to read objects concurrently, let alone read and write them concurrently, and the operating system may not even allow you to do the latter. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Why? What happens under the hood that makes it a bad thing?

Comment: if many threads are writing and reading you should have sinchronization or else the writing might be interrupted and gibberish would be written instead, and when reading threads might be reading something that has not been fully written

Comment: You haven't answered my question. What happens in your application that makes it a required thing? Serialization strongly implies sequentialization. Object streams are streams, not random-access files.

Comment: What if we change from file to `ArrayList<>`, is it ok now? I can get the readers obtain the current list size and then just iterate to that point, right?

Comment: That means every thread is reading the entire file, over and over again. If the list is large and/or the number of threads is high this does not scale. You *still* haven't answered my question. Why do you need to send yourself objects via a file?